# Checking whether try was executed or catch was executed in finally

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to check whether the control handed over to `finally` came from `try` or one of the `catch`es? 
Something like:

```
try {
    // Some code
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Some more code
} finally {
    // Check if control came from try or from catch?
}
```

Comment: You could add a `System.out.println()` within the catch block...

Comment: use a `Boolean` which you initialize with `true` in `try` and `false` in `catch`

Comment: I really wonder why you want to do this. This sounds to me like you are trying to control the flow with your try/catch which is an anti-pattern

Comment: @Bartzilla was just curious about it. Won't be using this in actual code.

Comment: Breakpoints and use debugger, use print output, or boolean flag with print output. Probably all possibilities which can you use.

Comment: one question: why do you think you need this?

Comment: @Eugene as I mentioned I was just curious about it and won't be using this.

Comment: understood, makes sense to read both upvoted answers in such a case. you usually should not care where you came from in finally, but if you *really* wanted to, using a boolean is the best (only?) case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no automated way to do it in Java. You can create a boolean flag:

```
boolean isRaised = false;

try {
    // Some code
}
catch (Exception e) {
    isRaised = true;
}
finally {
    if (isRaised)
        System.out.println("from catch");
    else
        System.out.println("from try");
}
```

Comment: If you load the `catch` block with more code (before setting the boolean), which could cause a blow-up, you might execute the code code for `try` as you have no distinct value between `try` and `not executed at all`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Setting the boolean value should be the first thing that happens in the catch block

Comment: "should" does not guarantee it. Using a `Boolean` simply eliminates that risk

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx Well, you never know what geniuses are coding

Comment: Yes, that is true :)

Comment: Note that the code may also throw any type of `Throwable`, not just an `Exception`. If you use a three-valued type such as `Boolean` then you can distinguish between (1) coming from try block, (2) coming from catch block, and (3) coming from some other thrown `Throwable` that isn't caught. But *only if you assign the Boolean at the end of your try block*.

Answer (score 4):

***Better not.***

The general pattern is:

```
try {
    someCodePossiblyRaisingAnException;
    preFinalOkayCode;
} catch (AbcException | DefException e) {
    preFinalFailedCode;
} finally {
    finalCode;
}
```

Especially using a non-specific Exception is considered bad style by most IDEs and code checkers.

It might be the code using an Exception indicates the desire for a general solution, and that repeated several times. In that case let the caller propagate the exception. For instance with java swing let button actions capture the exception by:

```
protected ExceptionlessButton { // Or Action
    @Override
    public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            onAction(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
    abstract protected void onAction(ActionEvent evt);
}
```

In the presented case the final code seems to belong to either one of the pre-final code parts. When considering **try-with-resources** that can often even eliminate finally-blocks, you might reconsider the need for such a generalisation.

```
Result f() throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement stm = ...) {
        someCodePossiblyRaisingAnException;
        preFinalOkayCode;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative how about:

```
try {
    // Some code
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Some more code
    //Code to execute for case where object thrown goes here.
    return; //Maybe return false or re-throw...
} finally{
    //Code to execute regardless of whether exception is thrown.
}
//Code to execute if no exception is thrown...
//return true;//?
```

This may need to be in a (`private`) function if the objective is to carry on after the `catch` case.

I'm just putting this forward because the idea of a `finally` clause is that it is code that is executed regardless of whether normal or exception-handling control flow takes place and the question is specifically looking for a way to execute different code in those two circumstances. So appears counter the purpose.

We have a pattern for that! It's a `catch` handler!

Code that is trying to figure that out is a 'code smell'.
It may be because the `try` block is too large and catching a variety of errors which ought to be sub-divided.

As others point out you can use flags to indicate certain points were reached but it's not normally the best approach.